# Firebase Cloud Functions, set ref parent in Unit Test

Tags: typescript, firebase, github, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have the following Firebase Cloud Function:

```js
functions.database.ref(`/users/{uid}/subscription`).onWrite((change, context) => {
    const uid = context.params.uid
    const value = change.after.val()

    if (!change.before.exists() && !value) {
      return null
    }

    return change.after.ref.parent?.once('value').then(snapshot => {
      const user = snapshot.val()
      console.warn(`user`, user)
      const email = user?.providerData?.email

      if (typeof email !== 'string') {
        return null
      }

      console.log('Update flag at Mailer', context.params.uid, email, fieldname)

      return createOrUpdateContact(uid, user)
    })
  })
```

And I am trying to write a test for it, using `firebase-functions-test` Google's Framework to mock the back-end implementation of Firebase:

```js
it('correctly updates flag at mailer', async (done) => {
    const userId = chance.guid();
    const userEmail = chance.email()
    const userAfter = {
      uid: userId,
      subscription: true,
      providerData: {
        email: userEmail
      }
    };

    const beforeSnap = functionsMock.database.makeDataSnapshot(
      {
        uid: userId,
        subscription: false,
        providerData: {
          email: userEmail
        }
      },
      `/users/${userId}`
    );

    const afterSnap = functionsMock.database.makeDataSnapshot(
      true,
      `/users/${userId}/subscription`
    );

    const wrapped = functionsMock.wrap(update_subscription_flag);

    const change = functionsMock.makeChange(beforeSnap, afterSnap);

    const res = await wrapped(change, {
      params: {
        uid: userId
      }
    });

    expect(res).toBeTruthy()

    expect(createOrUpdateContact).toHaveBeenCalledWith(userId, userAfter)


    done()
  } )
```

However, there is a problem when the test executes on this line:

```js
    return change.after.ref.parent?.once('value').then(snapshot => {
```

It should give the `parent` of the ref object (which is the subscription flag) and this effectively works when deployed, but on my test code, it returns `null` because the ref has no parent, is there any way to fix this behaviour? Forcefully set the parent of the changed value?

**Just FYI:** I tried using the full user object as the `afterSnap`, but then the Framework is even dumber and takes the after and before objects as the user objects and not just the property.

Cheers

Comment: From the code posted I understand you're testing the function in [offline mode](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/unit-testing#initializing) as mentioned in the documentation. Upon that, I wonder what is the `functionsMock` variable. Moreover if you could provide the full initialization part of the test script I would try reproducing on my end.

Comment: No, I'm testing in online-mode

Answer (score 1):

For completeness, here is the issue raised for this and the Firebase Functions Test repository on GitHub if it proves useful to anyone else.

- [Firebase Functions Test issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions-test/issues/84)
- [Firebase Functions Test Repository on GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions-test)